# Кавычки в названиях космодромов

Tags: кавычки

Почему названия космодромов не берутся в кавычки? Ни «Роскосмос», ни «Грамота.ру» не пишут «Байконур» в кавычках, они везде пишут так:

> Космодром Байконур

Есть какое-то правило или исключение, зафиксированное словарями?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что это имена собственные.
По той же причине не пишутся в кавычках:

> город Москва
> гора Арарат
> планета Земля